# call javascript function from html generated by another javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in javascript. As the title says, I'm trying to call javascript function from html generated by another javascript function. Following is a simple version of this code:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
      function myFunction1()
      {
         var html_text = "<HTML><BODY><FORM><INPUT type=\"button\" onClick=

\"myFunction2()\" value=\"function2\" /></FORM></BODY></HTML>";
         document.write(html_text);
         document.close();
      }

      function myFunction2()
      {
         alert("function2 called!");
      }
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <FORM><INPUT type="button" onClick="myFunction1()" value="function1" 

/></FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I run firebug, I got an error saying "myFunction2 is not defined". I guess I have to put myFunction2 in html code generated by myFunction1. So I changed my code like this:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
      function myFunction1()
      {
         var html_text = "<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT language=\"JavaScript

\">function myFunction2(){alert(\"function2 called!\");}

</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY><FORM><INPUT type=\"button\" onClick=\"myFunction2()\" 

value=\"function2\" /></FORM></BODY></HTML>";
         document.write(html_text);
         document.close();
      }

      /* function myFunction2()
      {
         alert("function2 called!");
      } */
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <FORM><INPUT type="button" onClick="myFunction1()" value="function1" 

/></FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, after this change I got some messy result and the firebug says "unterminated string literal for var html_text=...". Any suggestions?
Also, my actual myFunction2 is really big, if I have to insert it into the html generated by myFunction1, is there a good way to put it in? Also, the instructor doesn't want us to use a separate file. Thanks!

Comment: [You can't have `</script>` in a string in javascript](http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2007/04/25/using-script-in-a-javascript-literal/).

Comment: You can't use " inside "-strings, and same for '. You need to escape the quotes inside the strings.

Comment: You may not use document.write after the page has rendered

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
      function myFunction1()
      {
         var html_text = "<HTML><BODY><sc"+"ript type=\"text/javascript\">function myFunction2(){alert('im 2')}</sc"+"ript><FORM><INPUT type=\"button\" onClick=\"myFunction2()\" value=\"function2\" /></FORM></BODY></HTML>";
         document.write(html_text);
         document.close();
      }

      function myFunction2()
      {
         alert("function2 called!");
      }
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <FORM><INPUT type="button" onClick="myFunction1()" value="function1"

/></FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note that you cannot include `"<script>"` in a sttring, you must break it in to `"<scr" + "ipt>"`

Comment: Nor can you document.write after the page has rendered

Comment: Sorry, I know it's ugly but that what he requested :( duno why

Answer (score 0):

I've put your first version of code into http://jsfiddle.net/EwR6X/, and with one small amend - deleting couple of unwanted line breaks after `onClick=` - it works just fine.